# Need help. Touchscreen not working LG G3

Tags: touchscreen, bugs, lg-g3

Here's the deal, folks.
I've been having trouble with my LGG3. I initially had blue screen of death but I solved it by putting the motherboard in oven for 10 min.(Amazingly worked)
Had to do it often over last 3 months because occasionally the LGG3 heats up & loses wi-fi when I use google maps.
In my latest attempt to fix the wi-fi I put the motherboard in the oven again and I fixed the wi-fi, but now the touchscreen does not respond. I get the hardware key control mode message when I power off/power on.
Is there anyway to fix this problem, so I can use the touchscreen again?
If there is no solution, is there some way to retrieve all my data and information from the phone? Whenever I plug it into my computer the cell asks me to give my PC permission to access the phone, but because I can't use the touchscreen I can't give it permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the part about using the phone even though the touchscreen doesn't work:

You can use an [OTG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) cable, to plug a computer mouse into your phone and you will then be able to navigate through your phone with it. This way, you'll be able to allow your phone to connect to your computer.

[Here's](https://www.ebay.com/i/281885661174?chn=ps&ul_ref=http%253A%252F%252Frover.ebay.com%252Frover%252F1%252F711-117182-37290-0%252F2%253Fmpre%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.ebay.com%25252Fi%25252F281885661174%25253Fchn%25253Dps%2526itemid%253D281885661174%2526targetid%253D412648130149%2526device%253Dm%2526adtype%253Dpla%2526googleloc%253D9005929%2526poi%253D%2526campaignid%253D1058340657%2526adgroupid%253D54501636840%2526rlsatarget%253Dpla-412648130149%2526abcId%253D1133876%2526merchantid%253D101687237%2526gclid%253DCjwKCAiAtorUBRBnEiwAfcp_Y4NcSrBXjqJ8Go7oUq17Kwj6AUk79KXzbXa2zrO8Phpj1FwziRymwRoCL8YQAvD_BwE%2526srcrot%253D711-117182-37290-0%2526rvr_id%253D1440891675439&var=580861714507) an OTG cable that will allow you to connect your phone to the computer while having the mouse connected.

[image]